# Quick little puzzle-y Java thing

Tags: java

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better title.

Anyway, when I compile the following code:

```
class Example{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int x = 3;
        x -= 2 + x++ == 4 ? x++ : ++x;
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
    }
}
```

I get the answer -2. 
Now I would really like to know how it comes to this answer, as I can't find it.
It would be amazing if I could get an answer to this, as this may be on a exam that I'll have somewhat soon.
Note: Of course I wouldn't ever code out something like this myself, this is just an exercise.

Thanks so much if you can help me out!

Edit: answer to fge's answer:

Okay, thanks! but now if I change it up a little and make it like so:

```
    x = 2;
x += 3 + ++x == 6 ? x-- : x--;
System.out.println("x = " + x);
```

I would think that you would get the following:

```
++x == 6
```

is not true, as x is now 3. this means we get x--, making it now 2 again.

then we get 3 + 2 = 5, so the expression can be evaluated to:

```
x += 5
```

because x is now 2, we get 2 + 5 = 7.

Comment: Debugging won't really help in this case. Knowing the order of evaluation in Java may help though.

Comment: @LewsTherin is absolutely right :p Also, pre- and post-increment behavior.

Comment: Yea, but that's kinda the problem. I don't know in what order it operates. I tried figuring it out myself, but I couldn't find the answer, sadly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create such code example

```
int x = 3;
System.out.println(2 + x++ == 4 ? x++ : ++x);
```

you will see that the output is `5`. It is because it is equivalent to

`(2 + x++) == 4 ? x++ : ++x`

so first Java will evaluate (2+ x++). Since we have `x++` value of `x` will be returned first creating (2+3) and then incremented, so `x` will be now 4 after it.

Since `(2+3) == 4` is false because `(5 == 4)` we will execute this part `++x`, first incrementing `x` to 5 and then returning it.

---

Now lets go back to your example

```
int x = 3;
x -= 2 + x++ == 4 ? x++ : ++x;
```

You may know that `x -= y` is in fact `x = x - y` so it can be written as

```
x = x - (2 + x++ == 4 ? x++ : ++x);
```

So, since Java evaluates from left to right it will be

```
x = 3 - (2 + x++ == 4 ? x++ : ++x);
```

We know now that `(2 + x++ == 4 ? x++ : ++x)` is in fact `5` so

```
x = 3 - 5; // == -2
```

Comment: @fge not completely :) you just assumed that `x++ == 4` will be evaluated before `(2 + x++)`. Rest of your answer was quite interesting.

Comment: What I got completely wrong was precisely the fact that it was 2 + x++ which was evaluated :/

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thanks so much to the both of you for your time and effort :).

Comment: @user2491582 Glad we could help :)